# Django: django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'view_name' not found. 'view_name' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls, django-testing

I'm trying to run a test for my view and I get this error:
`Django: django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'create' not found. 'create' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

Here is my test:

```py
from django.urls import reverse
from django.test import TestCase
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.test import APIClient
from users.models import User

class UsersTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = APIClient()
        self.user = User.objects.create(chat_id=123456789, language='en')

    def test_create_valid_user(self):
        response = self.client.post(
            reverse('users:create'),
            data = {
            'chat_id': 1234,
            'language': 'en'
            },
            format='json'
        )
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        self.assertEqual(User.objects.count(), 2)
```

users/urls.py:

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'users'

urlpatterns = [
    path('get-all/', views.get_all),
    path('create/', views.create),
    path('get-by-chat-id/<int:chat_id>/', views.get_by_chat_id),
    path('update/<int:chat_id>/', views.update)
]
```

app/urls.py (main urls.py):

```py
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('users/', include('users.urls', namespace='users')),
]
```

output of `$ python manage.py show_urls`:

```bash
/users/create/  users.views.create      
/users/get-all/ users.views.get_all     
/users/get-by-chat-id/<int:chat_id>/    users.views.get_by_chat_id      
/users/update/<int:chat_id>/    users.views.update
```

I believe the `reverse('users:create')` raises the error, and I tried a lot of things and couldn't fix it.
Please tell me how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give the path that name:

```
app_name = 'users'

urlpatterns = [
    # …
    path('create/', views.create, name='create'),
    # …
]
```

Comment: then it gives: `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)` followed by `ImportError: rest_framework doesn't look like a module path` errors

Comment: @SRezaS: that is likely an additional problem in your view. The reverse one however should normally work now...